# Multiplying a specific cell of a tensor on tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Could not find an example anywhere.
Let's say I have a (4,3) tensor.
How can I for example multiply the first cell (1,1) of a tensor by 2?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

t = tf.range(12, dtype=tf.float32)
t = tf.reshape(t, [4, 3])
delta = t[1][1] * (2. - 1.)
delta = tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[1, 1]], values=[delta], dense_shape=[4, 3])
t = tf.sparse.add(t, delta)
```